# Скрол тела таблицы, но с фиксированным заголовком

Tags: jquery, css

Есть таблица https://jsfiddle.net/ozrhgw04/4/. Как сделать Скрол тела таблицы, но с фиксированным заголовком

```js
var $table = $('table.tftable');
$table.on('change', '.chk-all', function() {
  var
    index = $(this).closest('th').index(),
    selector = `td:nth-child(${index + 1}) input[type="checkbox"]`,
    checked = this.checked;

  $table.find(`tr ${selector}`).prop('checked', checked);
  $table.find('tr').slice(1).filter(function() {
    return !$(this)
      .find('.green')
      .closest('td')
      .toArray()
      .map(n => $(n).index())
      .filter(n => n !== index)
      .filter(n => $table.find(`tr:first th:nth-child(${n + 1}) input:checked`).length).length;
  }).detach().sort(function(a, b) {
    var
      aGreen = $(a).find(selector).hasClass('green'),
      bGreen = $(b).find(selector).hasClass('green');

    return (bGreen ^ aGreen) ? [1, -1][+(checked ^ bGreen)] : 0;
  }).appendTo($table);
});
```

```css
.green {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<table class="tftable" border="1">
    <tbody><tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>
<div class="subject-tile" style="width: auto;">
<div class="subject-tile-img-wrapper rounded" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 7px;">
<a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/belaya-tehnika/"><img class="img-fluid" src="/templates/pokupatel/images/icons/Белая техника.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" alt="Белая техника" style="width: 70px; height: 50px;" data-original-title="Белая техника"></a>
</div>
</div>
    <br> <input type="checkbox" name="category71" class="chk-all">
</th><th>
<div class="subject-tile" style="width: auto;">
<div class="subject-tile-img-wrapper rounded" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 7px;">
<a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/vstroennaya-tehnika/"><img class="img-fluid" src="/templates/pokupatel/images/icons/Встроенная техника.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" alt="Встроенная техника" style="width: 70px; height: 50px;" data-original-title="Встроенная техника"></a>
</div>
</div>
    <br> <input type="checkbox" name="category72" class="chk-all">
</th><th>
<div class="subject-tile" style="width: auto;">
<div class="subject-tile-img-wrapper rounded" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 7px;">
<a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/klimaticheskaya-tehnika/"><img class="img-fluid" src="/templates/pokupatel/images/icons/Климатическая техника.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" alt="Климатическая техника" style="width: 70px; height: 50px;" data-original-title="Климатическая техника"></a>
</div>
</div>
    <br> <input type="checkbox" name="category73" class="chk-all">
</th><th>
<div class="subject-tile" style="width: auto;">
<div class="subject-tile-img-wrapper rounded" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 7px;">
<a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/melkaya-domashnyaya-tehnika/"><img class="img-fluid" src="/templates/pokupatel/images/icons/Мелкая домашняя техника.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" alt="Мелкая домашняя техника" style="width: 70px; height: 50px;" data-original-title="Мелкая домашняя техника"></a>
</div>
</div>
    <br> <input type="checkbox" name="category74" class="chk-all">
</th><th>
<div class="subject-tile" style="width: auto;">
<div class="subject-tile-img-wrapper rounded" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 7px;">
<a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/melkaya-kuhonnaya-tehnika/"><img class="img-fluid" src="/templates/pokupatel/images/icons/Мелкая кухонная техника.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" alt="Мелкая кухонная техника" style="width: 70px; height: 50px;" data-original-title="Мелкая кухонная техника"></a>
</div>
</div>
    <br> <input type="checkbox" name="category75" class="chk-all">
</th><th>
<div class="subject-tile" style="width: auto;">
<div class="subject-tile-img-wrapper rounded" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 7px;">
<a href="http://pokupatel.pro/dom/bytovaya-tehnika/tehnika-dlya-krasoty/"><img class="img-fluid" src="/templates/pokupatel/images/icons/Техника для красоты.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" alt="Техника для красоты" style="width: 70px; height: 50px;" data-original-title="Техника для красоты"></a>
</div>
</div>
    <br> <input type="checkbox" name="category76" class="chk-all">
</th>
    </tr>
      <tr>  
          <td>
           <img src="/uploads/posts/2018-07/1531344803_tenex_logo.png" alt="{name}" style="width: 215px; height: 70px;"><br>
              <span class="title">Техснабэкспорт</span> <br> 
              <span class="adress">Весенняя 56</span> <br>
              <span class="phone">+79526036525</span> <br>
              <span class="site">pok.ru</span> <br>
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           
            <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="category">
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
</tr>      <tr>  
          <td>
           <img src="/uploads/posts/2018-07/1531344702_hunter_logo.png" alt="{name}" style="width: 215px; height: 70px;"><br>
              <span class="title">Hunter Industries</span> <br> 
              <span class="adress">Весенняя 55</span> <br>
              <span class="phone">+79526036525</span> <br>
              <span class="site">pok.ru</span> <br>
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           
            <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="category">
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
</tr>      <tr>  
          <td>
           <img src="/uploads/posts/2018-07/1531344695_logo-vedtranzit-b.png" alt="{name}" style="width: 215px; height: 70px;"><br>
              <span class="title">ВЭД ТРАНЗИТ</span> <br> 
              <span class="adress">Весенняя 54</span> <br>
              <span class="phone">+79526036525</span> <br>
              <span class="site">pok.ru</span> <br>
        </td>
       <td>
           
            <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="category">
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
</tr>      <tr>  
          <td>
           <img src="" alt="{name}" style="width: 215px; height: 70px;"><br>
              <span class="title">Компания #2</span> <br> 
              <span class="adress"></span> <br>
              <span class="phone"></span> <br>
              <span class="site"></span> <br>
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           
            <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="category">
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
</tr>      <tr>  
          <td>
           <img src="/uploads/posts/2018-07/1530961289_mvideo_1996.png" alt="{name}" style="width: 215px; height: 70px;"><br>
              <span class="title">Компания #1</span> <br> 
              <span class="adress">Весенняя 54</span> <br>
              <span class="phone">+79526036525</span> <br>
              <span class="site">http://pokupatel.pro</span> <br>
        </td>
       <td>
           
            <input class="green" type="checkbox" name="category">
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
       <td>
           <input class="black" type="checkbox" name="category">
            
        </td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Для начала http://htmlbook.ru/HTML/THEAD http://htmlbook.ru/html/tbody

Comment: и? что это я понять не могу

Comment: `<table class="tftable" border="1"><tbody>` Ваше? как вы собрались отличать шапку(thead) от тела(tbody) если вся таблица(включая шапку) у вас запихнута в тело?

Comment: Я понял, а можно сделать, чтоб 1 tr с классом fixed был шапкой?

Comment: Можно, но никак не пойму с какой целью эти извращения если всё придумано за нас?

Comment: Да я тупанул, а переделывать много(((

Comment: а вы думаете в вашем варианте вам меньше переделывать? в любом случае без контейнера вам обойтись не удастся. т.е. шапка в одном контейнере, данные в другом, иначе никак =) и да `<tr>` не контейнер

Comment: Ок. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oc95satd/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oc95satd/1/ а если я так пределал?

Comment: Ну результат вас устраивает? это работет? в чем тогда вопрос?

Comment: Да я решил правильно сделать, как вы выше писали. По стандарту. Можете туда стили накинуть, если ширина таблицы 100%?

Comment: При ширине 100% будут глюки =) ширина фиксированая должна быть =) ну собсно уже в вашем примере видны глюки =)

Comment: понял, 927px нужно

Comment: ВСе равно как то ячейки не ровные по сравнению с шапкой

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oc95satd/2/